# Up and out barrier options clarification

Tags: finance

Let $c_{uo}$(K, L) denote the price of a 1-year Apple European down-and-out
call with strike $K$ and barrier $L$.

Assume the spot price is $80$. Using only no-arbitrage, describe as many (in)equalities that can be derived
comparing the five quantities:
$$0, c_{uo}(101, 120), c_{uo}(101, 110), c_{uo}(111, 110)$$

From what I can understand, when we have a fixed K with no arbitrage, the price of the lower barrier is more than (or equal to) the price of the higher barrier.

How does the spot price and K enter these comparison?

Comment: Your question title is down and out barrier but your question setup is up and out.

Comment: Your spot price will not affect the option price inequalities. The price of your fourth option should be obvious. You just got to rank the other two quantities.

Comment: Should I just follow the logic of what I understand, which is comparing the barrier prices?

Comment: Yes, compare the barrier prices. Just think about it logically.